# Run a Thread in an infinite loop without running out of memory

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method called `Update` it's called from an infinite loop,
In that method I have another for loop that loops through a List,

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < Apps.Count;i++) { /* Code */ }
```

In that loop, I have a method being called that slows down the process if it is run (~250 FPS to ~55 FPS).
If I do

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < Apps.Count;i++) { new Thread(() => /* Method */ ).Start(); }
```

It uses up all the threads and the Process crashes. How could I run that method without using all the threads.

**Important**
I am using Bare metal C#

Comment: You might want to look into using [`Parallel.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)

Comment: The [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem) method might be a starting point. *"I cannot use anything in `System.Threading.Tasks`"* <== could we ask why?

Comment: I cannot use `System.Threading.Tasks` because I'm developing an OS in C# (the compiler is https://github.com/nifanfa/MOSA-Core) It does not support some System dll's

Comment: Elijah629 in that case it's unfortunate, but you may end up reinventing the [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) type, and implementing it from scratch.

Comment: Can you compile `IEnumerable` generators, abuse that to create resumable co-routines (similar to unity) as a task replacement?

Answer (score -2):

may limit the count of the active threads with a small helper class/ helper thread that manages how many Threads are active at the same time and use it like that

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var iterator = i;//note the iterator in a for loop isn't declared inside it's inner scope and will change on increment, similar also for foreach
    threadHelper.AddAction(() => { /* do stuff */ });

}
/* some more code that dont need the results of the threads*/

threadHelper.WaitForEnd();
```

Not worked with the pure thread class before only did something similar with tasks before and it probably needs some drastic optimization but my naive approach would be something like this

```
public class ThreadHelper
{
    private Thread[] Threads;
    private Thread CheckThread;
    private Queue<Action> Actions = new Queue<Action>();
    private int UpdateSpeed;
    public int RunnignThreads = 0;
    public bool Completed => RunnignThreads == 0 && !Actions.Any();



       public ThreadHelper(int maxThreads, int updateSpeed)
        {
            Threads = new Thread[maxThreads];
            UpdateSpeed = updateSpeed;
            // small thread to check if new actions should be executed
            CheckThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < Threads.Length; i++)
                    {
                        //remove completed threads
                        if (!(Threads[i]?.IsAlive ?? true))
                        {
                            RunnignThreads--;
                            Threads[i] = null;
                        }
                        //add new
                        lock (Actions)
                        {
                            if (Threads[i] == null && Actions.Any())
                            {
    
                                var threadAction = Actions.Dequeue();
                                Threads[i] = new Thread(() => threadAction());
                                Threads[i].Start();
                                RunnignThreads++;
                            }
    
                        }
    
                    }
                    // just a small delay to 
                    Thread.Sleep(updateSpeed);
                }
            });
            CheckThread.Start();
        }

        ~ThreadHelper()
        {
            CheckThread.Abort();
        }
    
        public void AddAction(Action action)
        {
            lock (Actions)
            {
                Actions.Enqueue(action);
            }
        }
        //Maybe the waiting is a little bit trickier...
        public void WaitForEnd()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(UpdateSpeed *2 ); //maybe no threads are even startet before this gets called
            while (!Completed)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(UpdateSpeed);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `CheckThread.Abort()`: the [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort) method is no longer supported in the .NET platform. It throws a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

Comment: ohh didn't saw it - I should read the compiler warnings :) In this case something like a cancelationtoken seems to be necessary. Interesting that they removed it in .net 5. It makes sense that it can be dangerous but recently even had a good use case for it working with .net framework where i had no control over the code of a very long call that seemed to be mostly save for it

Comment: Mucksh AFAIK the recommended approach when invoking external not cancelable APIs that take too long or have a tendency to deadlock, is to invoke them on a separate `AppDomain` that can be  unloaded, or even better on a separate process that can be killed.

Comment: Could be possible. Thanks would be a safer solution